# What tool can give me a hourly reminder?

Tags: windows-xp, timer, alert, reminder

I'm looking for a tool, that can alert me every hour with a popup and a message (like "take your medicine..") I'm running Windows XP.

Comment: I found Windows' Task Scheduler hard to use, so I wrote a python script to automate tasks. Perhaps you could look into something similar?

Comment: @Phoshi - /offtopic/ That dark red color on the website (linked in your profile) is makes the page *really* hard to read , and my eyes start to ache. Why don't you use a white/light-grey background? ^^"

Comment: @Shiki: Because, my friend, I am an appallingly bad designer. I'm surprised you didn't comment about either of the blog styles, both of which have been known to kill small children (The root site has only killed newborn babies and the elderly :P)

Comment: @Phoshi: The main page (yours) is kinda nice. Like a children's room, but thats what is exceptional, nice about it. Like an old guy's 'web room', can't explain it. Nice. :) The other one.. the font/webpage color. Just apply a light grey/white bg or something like that since this way I cant even read the text. :/

Comment: @Shiki: You're probably right, I'll make a note somewhere to take a poke at the colours next time I get a chance :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task scheduler.

Create task (at the right) :
Name: Medicine
Desc: whatyouwant
Trigger tab:  NEW

Begin: on a schedule
Settings: Daily
Advanced settings (bottom):
Repeat task every: (set it however you want) 1 hour | for a duration: Indefinitely

**Actions**:
*Display a message*
Title: Medicine
Message: Take your medicine.

---

Screenshots:

[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

Comment: Only if OP is on Windows :)

Comment: Whoops. Hope it is. But if not, I'll write one for Linux, no prob. No stop for those medicines. ;P

Comment: Unfortunately we still stuck on Win XP and the Task Scheduler doesn't allow to trigger every hour. Just daily... and i'm dead if take my medicines only once a day ;-)

Comment: @gsharp If you create a schedule item, open it and click on the `Advanced` button on the `Schedule` tab there is a `Repeat task` option which can be set to `Every 1 hours`

Comment: @gsharp - Please do as Shevek wrote. XP supports the same. ^^"

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome there exists a [Timer Applet](http://timerapplet.sourceforge.net/) which provides such (or very similar) functionality.