# Program that displays a message at a certain hour on your screen?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, reminder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tool can give me a hourly reminder?](https://superuser.com/questions/150095/what-tool-can-give-me-a-hourly-reminder)

I'm a programmer, I often spend alot of time in front of my computer and forget about other things. I simply get drawn into my work and I cannot focus on anything else.

I have been searching for a program that displays a message on your computer screen on a set hour to remind me of certain things. Does such a program exist?

Comment: Windows XP, sorry I forgot to mention my OS.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. The above question should probably also answer yours!

Comment: I tried that answer above (Thanks for that, by the way) but there's no such thing as "Task scheduler" in "Administrative tools" in control panel. I'm on windows XP.

Comment: @ThePla Go to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools, and it is called 'Scheduled Tasks'.... Or, just go to the control panel, switch to the classic view, and there is a folder called 'Scheduled Tasks' as well.

Comment: You may be interested in this:  http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/

Answer (score 1):

I use Outlook. I find it to be an excellent tool.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I write such program for myself simplify reminders addition.

It's available for free: http://ficusdev.com/PostponeIt/Description

Warning: I'm not sure it will be actively developed in the nearest future.